# Oracle Tree Hierarchy Reverse Traverse Parent

Tags: sql, oracle11g, tree

I have the following sample data (see below), from an Oracle tree hierarchy, specifically using the `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(link_id, '/') as Path`

Assuming I am using the typical oracle tree query, i.e.:

```
SELECT link_id, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(link_id, '/') "Path"
FROM my_table
START WITH parent_link_id = 'L1'
CONNECT BY PRIOR link_id = parent_link_id;
```

Data Sample is:

```
L1   /LINK-A/QWERTY/QEDED1SA/AAAA|BBBB|CCCC/XX|YY|ZZ/L1

L2   /LINK-B/QETRYAB/QWERTY/L2
```

Now, what I am unsure how to do is, using the path sample data, I need a means of reverse traversing my path data from the bottom up, to determine and return the first "Q" starting string for that link id, which is the parent of that link id.

For example:

```
for Link_ID: L1, I want to grab and return the value: QEDED1SA and ignore AAAA|BBBB|CCCC/XX|YY|ZZ/

for Link_ID: L2, I want to grab the value: QWERTY
```

I would actually like to retrieve this parent "Q" string value as part of my tree query path as another column after "Path"

Basically branch up the tree path of that link, until you hit a parent that starts with the letter "Q" and return that whole value alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this expression for your additional column:

```
regexp_substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(link_id, '/'), '/(Q[^/]*)(/[^Q]|[^/])*$', 1, 1, '', 1)
```

It finds in `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(link_id, '/')` the last occurrence of a part that starts with `Q`.

The arguments `1, 1, ''` are just the default values for those parameters, but they are provided so that the last argument can be specified. That argument says to not return the whole match, but only the first capture group, i.e. whatever is matched by `Q[^/]*`. All the rest in the regular expression is there to make sure no other such part is following it.

Comment: tried your approach using select regexp_substr('/LINK-B/QETRYAB/QWERTY/L2', '(Q[^/]*)(/[^Q]|[^/])*$', 1, 1, '') a from dual
 but when I  run this query, I get back QWERTY/L2 I actually just want QWERTY Any ideas?

Comment: But that is not the query I suggested. You only provided 5 arguments, but you need to add the 6th argument: `1`. Also add the slash at the start of the regular expression.

Comment: Sorry @trincot but if you see my data sample above, I actually provided two scenarios, one that has 3 arguments and the other that has 5. I am simply trying to return the whole "Q" value without the start and end slashes but only the very last entry from right to left.